# Style the picker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm doing a login form in Swiftui, however when i try to add a form that contain picker for age the style get messed up and since im new to SwiftUI i didn't know how can i fix this problem?

How can i fix the picker style so it addapte with the Nickname field?

here it is the code that i tried:

```
@State var nickName: String = ""
@State var age: Int = 18

var body: some View {
VStack {
    
    
    
    HStack {
        
        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
            .foregroundColor(Color("ChatiwVeryLightBlue"))
            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
            .background(Color.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous))
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.15), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
            .padding(.all, 10)
        
        
        TextField("Nickname", text: $nickName)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 50)
    }
    
    Divider().padding(.leading, 80)
    
    
    HStack {
        
        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
            .foregroundColor(Color("ChatiwVeryLightBlue"))
            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
            .background(Color.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous))
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.15), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
            .padding(.all, 10)
        
      
        Form {
        Section {
            
            Picker(selection: $age, label: Text("Picker")) {
                ForEach(18 ..< 99, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("\(index)").tag(1)
                }
            }
            
        }
        }
       
                
        
    }

    // Age
    // Country
    // Male/Female
    
    
}
.background(BlurView(blurType: .systemMaterial))
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous))
.padding()
.offset(y: 400)
```

[image: Style SwiftUI]

Comment: Have you tried the different picker styles that can be applied to the picker using the [`pickerStyle(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/pickerstyle(_:)) modifier? See the Conforming Types section in [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/pickerstyle#relationships). For example, you could try `.pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())`

Comment: i did try them didn't work well for me

Comment: *"How can i fix the picker style so it addapte with the Nickname field?"* - What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @pawello2222 check the nickname field? do you see the design how it is? i want the picker field as well to look the same as this field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still working on this project, but here is a neat workaround:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var age = 18
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Divider()
                
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: AgePickerView(age: $age)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Age")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(age) >")
                                .padding(.trailing)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
                Divider()
            }
            .padding(.leading, 80)
        }
    }
    
    struct AgePickerView: View {
        @Binding var age: Int
        
        var body: some View {
            List(18..<99) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    self.age = index
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(index)")
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        if index == age {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get the same NavigationView style but remove the Form style, you need to wrap a NavigationLink in a NavigationView.

The little > sign I put at the end of the Text view in the NavigationLink doesn't perfectly match the one in the Form style, so you can look around for an image that is more similar if you would like.

The AgePickerView is pretty straightfoward; it's just a list of buttons that are modifying a binding to the original state variable in ContentView through tap gestures. The checkmark is there to imitate a Picker view.

The best part of this is that you don't have to worry about all that index shifting with a picker.